# Problema con tildes en Regex

Tags: java, regex

Estoy usando la web https://regex101.com/ . Usando como expresión regular la frase:

```
(?i)purificación
```

Y como texto

```
PURIFICACIÓN
```

Para mi sorpresa no machean, pensaba que el modificador de **case insensitive (i)** solucionaría esto, pero no lo hace. ¿Alguna idea?

PD: Hacerle un replaceAll al texto y cambiar Ó por O no es una opción valida (para mí) muy a mi pesar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

De forma predeterminada, `(?i)` asume sólo caracteres en el juego US-ASCII. No obstante, puedes habilitar la coincidencia sin distinción entre mayúsculas y minúsculas en Unicode utilizando una de las dos siguientes formas:

- #### Banderas embebidas

  Agrega la bandera `u` para habilitar la coincidencia sin distinción entre mayúsculas y minúsculas en Unicode. Es decir:

  ```
  public static void main (String[] args) {
      String str = "PURIFICACIÓN";
      System.out.println(
          str.matches("(?iu)purificación") 
      ); // imprime "true"
  }
  ```
- #### Máscara de bits

  Otra forma es especificando las banderas correspondientes en una máscara de bits en el método [`compile`](http://bit.ly/2biRcAC) de la clase [`Pattern`](http://bit.ly/2biRBTL). Esto es:

  ```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
      String input = "PURIFICACIÓN";
      Pattern regexPattern = Pattern.compile("purificación", 
              Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.UNICODE_CASE);
      System.out.println(
          regexPattern.matcher(input).matches()
      );  // imprime "true"
  }
  ```

  La máscara de bits puede incluir [`CASE_INSENSITIVE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#CASE_INSENSITIVE), [`MULTILINE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#MULTILINE), [`DOTALL`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#DOTALL), [`UNICODE_CASE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#UNICODE_CASE), [`CANON_EQ`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#CANON_EQ), [`UNIX_LINES`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#UNIX_LINES), [`LITERAL`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#LITERAL), [`UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS) y [`COMMENTS`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#COMMENTS).

---

**Sumario**

A continuación, la lista de banderas que puedes utilizar con su correspondiente bandera embebida (si existe):

```
+-------------------------+------+
| UNIX_LINES              | (?d) |
| CASE_INSENSITIVE        | (?i) |
| COMMENTS                | (?x) |
| MULTILINE               | (?m) |
| LITERAL                 |      |
| DOTALL                  | (?s) |
| UNICODE_CASE            | (?u) |
| CANON_EQ                |      |
| UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS | (?U) |
+-------------------------+------+
```

Answer (score 0):

La solución es agregar el modificar `u`a la expresión regular. Con este modificador le indicas que el patrón será tratado como un string UTF-16 y no ASCII.

te adjunto un screenshot del cambio en regex101:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
cada modificador significa:

- i: case insensitive
- u: trata el patrón como UTF-16
- m: haces matches multilínea
- g: hace una match de forma global, retornando todos los calces

por último, te recomiendo utilizar el modificador `i` como modificador del patrón y no como lo agregaste:

```
/purificación/imug <- trata de forma insensitive TODO el patrón
/(?i)purificación/imug <- trata de forma insensitive **a partir** del donde lo pongas
```

por ejemplo:
`/a(?i)purificación/mug` calza con 'apurificación', 'aPURIFICACIÓN', 'aPUrifICAciÓn', etc. Siempre con la primera 'a' minuscula

en cambio: `/apurificación/imug` calza con 'apurificación', 'Apurificación', 'apuRriFICación', etc. Ya no importa si la 'a' es mayúscula o minúscula.

Comment: Una respuesta buenisima. Lo que pasa es que no veo como pasarle el modificador (u)  al Pattern de java.
Lo que si que he visto que puedo hacer buscar esto purificaci\Xn y posiblemente me valdría.

Comment: el problema ya es otro en este caso. No conozco mucho Java, pero según leo en https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html Unicode Support, deberías escapar tu caracter a su forma unicode y con eso podrías hacer el match.

Comment: Si si, por eso te he dado la respuesta como válida. Muchas gracias caballero!

Comment: claro, pero el problema es que específico para la palabra y poco escalable en el tiempo. quizás convirtiendo los caracteres unicode a su par ascii en una variable temporal y haciendo match en ascii sería mas escalable